# jQuery.ajax error: Unexpected token ":"

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to get a function to make a web request successfully and retrieve some JSON data, but I keep getting the same error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

This is what I have setup right now:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://[website url]/json/',
            context: this,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            contentType:  "application/json"
        }).done(function(response){
           alert("here");//this is meant for testing purposes--the code never seems to get this far
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

I feel like I'm close to getting things setup correctly but apparently I'm still missing something. I tried using json instead of jsonp but that did not work since I'm calling to a different domain than what I'm on. The JSON data is setup correctly from what I can tell:

```
{"Name":"[Value]","Estimated Time":"[Time Estimate]"}
```

Am I missing something inside $.ajax? Or is there something wrong with the setup of the JSON data?

Comment: The error is probably in the data returned from your web service.

Comment: Where's the data you're passing?

Comment: Open up the development tools for your browser or better yet use Fiddler and see what your getting back. I'm guessing its a CORS issue.

Comment: Why set contentType if you have no data parameter?